# Generative Network Sampling: spherical interpolation instead of linear?

Tags: normal-distribution, neural-networks, random-generation, generative-models, gan

I am building my own implementation of a [DCGAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06434.pdf) at the moment and want to try different random samplings for the Generator's input (noise).

Recently, I found the paper [Sampling Generative Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04468.pdf). I understand the author's claim that for the Generator's input $z$ (e.g. 100-dimensional, which is kind of "standard size") a standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ is not the best choice, since it will have "tent poles" of length approx. close to 10 (see chap. 2.1).

However, I struggle understanding why the spherical version solves this "issue" and why this (heavily?) improves generative networks.

Additionally, the author gives the following formula for the spherical version:

$$
Slerp(q_1, q_2, \mu) = \frac{\sin(1-\mu)*\theta}{\sin(\theta)} * q_1 + \frac{sin(\mu * \theta)}{sin(\theta)} * q_2
$$

...but he does not explain what $q1, q2, \theta$ is?

Can someone help?

Instead of the typical:

```
# Python code
z = np.random.standard_normal((batch_size, 100)).astype(np.float32)
```

...which is already more stable than a uniform distribution for my network, thus I would really like to further enhance the random sampling.